# websockets not working when trying to foward with nginx

Tags: python, flask, nginx, websocket, flask-socketio

I am trying to foward localhost:4000 -> localhost:8000 i am using nginx its working fine for static pages but when i try to use websockets it doesnt work

here is the code im using:

server.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, namespace='/counter')

def counter_thread():
    count = 0
    while count <= 100:
        socketio.emit('counter_update', {'count': count}, namespace='/counter')
        count += 1
        socketio.sleep(1)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

@app.route('/time1')
def time1():
    return render_template('counter.html')

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/counter')
def counter_connect():
    global count_thread
    if 'count_thread' not in globals():
        count_thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=counter_thread)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, port=4000)
```

counter.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Real-time Counter</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.3.1/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Real-time Counter</h1>
    <div id="counter"></div>

    <script>
        var socket = io.connect("http://"+ document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/counter');

        socket.on('counter_update', function(data) {
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 'Counter: ' + data.count;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

my nginx conf is:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen       8000;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
}
```

access.log(small sample):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2024:01:46:27 +0200] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=0W0s74jOOVnn1CoIAAAE HTTP/1.1" 400 36 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2024:01:46:27 +0200] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OvZQAl-&sid=0W0s74jOOVnn1CoIAAAE HTTP/1.1" 400 36 "http://127.0.0.1:8000/time1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2024:01:46:28 +0200] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OvZQAmX&sid=0W0s74jOOVnn1CoIAAAE HTTP/1.1" 400 36 "http://127.0.0.1:8000/time1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

static stuff is fine but the sockets arent working:

[port4000(working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYczx.png)

[port8000forwardof4000(not working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUXa9.png)

now im not sure if this is a problem with my setup for sockets or if this is a problem with my nginx.conf

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console?